# Fontawesome icon not showing in front of anchor tag in HTML

Tags: html, font-awesome

My **HTML** code:

```
<i class="fas fa-desktop-arrow-down fa-fade">&ensp;</i><a href="/app-debug.apk" download>You can download this app from here</a>
```

When I run the HTML page, the `fontawesome` icon doesn't show.

I have also included my kit in my `HTML` page:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03d58ba9c7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use classes like these:

```
class="fa fa-desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an Paid icon
you can check [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/desktop-arrow-down?s=regular&f=classic)

Answer (score 0):

I have used 4.7 icons.

```
<i class="fa fa-download">&ensp;</i><a href="/app-debug.apk" download>You can download this app from here</a>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/webdev0904/tsz4Lfc2/11/)